# Problema con coding de exportación en Python / JSON

Tags: python, tweepy

estoy retomando python después de algunos años haciendo ejercicios con tweepy y tengo problemas al exportar tweets a JSON.

```
datos = {}
datos['tuits'] = []
for tweets in x.search(q='#EstoPasaEnChile',count=3, result_type='recent', lang = "es"):
    datos['tuits'].append({
       'username': tweets.user.screen_name,
       'contenido': tweets.text})
    print (datos)
with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
   json.dump(datos, file, indent=3)
```

Ese es mi código en Python y los resultados en el archivo json quedan con el siguiente problema:

```
"contenido": "RT @sesirisa: Ahora en #Concepci\u00f3n se ve humo sobre el techo de la provincial de la Gobernaci\u00f3n Provincial de Concepci\u00f3n #orquestasinfonica\u2026"
```

Cómo puedo hacer para quitar los "`\u00f3`"?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes pasarle como argumento `ensure_ascii=False` a `json.dump` para que no se comporte de esa manera.

De la documentación de json.dump (`help(json.dump)`)

> If `ensure_ascii` is false, then the strings written to `fp` can
>       contain non-ASCII characters if they appear in strings contained in
>       `obj`. Otherwise, all such characters are escaped in JSON strings.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta.

cuando le paso este argumento, el `contenido`, se me ve así:

`"RT @andaisimpatica: \"La gente est� cansada\", si pero de toda desigualdad que hay en Chile. \n\n#HabraConsecuencias\n#EstoPasaEnChile #EstoNoHa�"`

Comment: @Fernando Debe ser un problema con el encoding, proba poniendolo explicitamente cuando abrís el archivo `open("data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: ahora no me da error al correr el archivo, sin embargo, se vuelven a leer así los resultados: `no s\u00e9 si tiene Twitter, los cabros puro Insta, estudia sociolog\u00eda en\u2026`

Comment: Hola, finalmente esta respuesta estaba en lo correcto. 
El problema era del VSC.

Answer (score 0):

Tu cadena no está en una codificación que soporte acentos y otros caracteres latinos.

Puedes cambiar la codificación de tu cadena con la siguiente línea:

```
 tweets.text.encode().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `json.dump(datos, file, indent=3).encode().decode('utf-8')`

lo tengo así e igual falla

Comment: Esta parte no se aplica a `json.dump` sino a `datos`.